# React-router and google cached pages for SPA

Tags: reactjs, caching, seo, react-router, google-search

I have a question about react-router and google cached pages in the results of google. In this case we have a SPA, which uses react-router (via browserHistory), the problem here is that: google cached page is a page wrapper, where the URL-a differs by the URL defined in the router of the SPA, in this case the routing of the application falls to the definition of a page not found.
(example )

and the cached result of SPA page by google, instead showing the content of the page is displayed component PageNotFoundApp (routing for page not found *).

Do you have any idea, what could be done about the resolving of the described problem?

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to intercept the routing logic by using the `onEnter` event

```
const projectCanonnicalAddr = "http://localhost";
function cacheQueryParser(query) {
    let out = '';
    if (typeof query === 'string') {
        out = query.split(':').pop().replace(/^[^/]*/, '');
    }
    return out;
}
function intercepPath(next, replace) {
    if (next.location.pathname === '/search' 
        && next.location.query.q 
        && next.location.query.q.indexOf('cache') === 0 
        && next.location.query.q.indexOf(projectCanonnicalAddr) > -1) {
            replace(null, cacheQueryParser(next.location.query.q));
    } 
};
```

After this, for the catch-all the route definition you can use something like this:

```
<Route path="*" component={PageNotFoundApp.container} onEnter={intercepPath}/>
```

Please note that using of the injected `replace` function would actually navigate the browser to the path provided as a second parameter. I have not tested this in the case with google cache and it might be a wrong implementation.
As an option you could pass a valid state as the first parameter of this function.

Comment: onEnter no longer availaible with react router v4

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem might be bypass to loading of SPA if domain name is different. And it have a sense only when pages have fallback HTML version used when JavaScript disabled (see: https://web.dev/without-javascript/).

For example, HTML pages of SPA have to a base href

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="https://example.com">
        ...
```

And `index.js` might be like this

```
let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
let base = head.getElementsByTagName("base")[0];
let domain = base.href.replace('https://', '');

if (window.location.host === domain) {
  import('./App');
} else {
  const root = document.getElementById("root");
  root.classList.remove('loader');
  // or something else
}
```

As a result, the search engines will index single page application, but  if open the pages from the google cache, the fallback HTML pages will be shown.